# What to do about my on-topic self-promoting answers marked as Spam?

Tags: support, specific-answer, self-promotion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow posts:

1. [Is JVM for MIPS available?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54408279/10885864)
   [image]
2. [Which JRE or JDK can I manually install on a armv7l linux with less than 55Mb available?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54408407/10885864)
   [image]

I believe that the above answers were both marked as spam because of their textual similarities and potentially also because of the self-promotion elements.

My understanding based on these posts..

1. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302
2. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265652/10885864
3. https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

.. was that self-promotion is allowed, as long as its done sparingly, and it answers the question.

In both cases, I picked posts to answer that either were asked recently or had recent activity.  I not only tried to answer the question, but also to provide objective evidence that backs up the statement (comparable RAM/Heap usage).  Finally, I also fully disclosed the fact that I worked for the company.

As a new user, I wasn't quite aware, but now fully understand that self-promotion is frowned upon.  Moving forward, I don't intend to just plug the company for which I work.  I promise to do this sparingly.  Rather, my intent is to transfer the knowledge I've acquired over the years of working with the Java programming language and with different JVM's.

All that being said, are there any steps that I can/should take to unlock the above posts so that they could be edited/improved?  If so, how can they be improved?  Or are they permanently locked/marked as spam and I should just move on and work on generating other good answers/content?

Comment: When you have an account where *literally all* of the answers are self promotion for your product, it's spam *as is made clear in the links you provided*.

Comment: Just FTR: in both cases the question was also off-topic, they are both closed now, one deleted (it only contained outdated and low-quality answers).

Comment: These answers address the questions, but the questions themselves are off-topic. The main reason they're off-topic is to prevent product recommendation answers like yours. You should not answer off-topic questions. As for the gist of your answers, advertisement-talk (_one of our top architectures_) and inviting off-site contact are both bad. You should keep your answers factual and minimal.

Comment: Oof.  Those both read like marketing materials.  That's going to hit anybody's spam triggers, no matter how relevant and on-topic they are.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  I'll give you that at least two of those answers on the MIPS question were poor because the links they rely on are now out-of-date.  However, Debian *still* does [target MIPS with its JDK8 binaries](https://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-8-jdk), so deleting the entire question wholesale would indicate that *something* of value might have been lost in the noise.

Comment: @Makoto: *very little* of value has been lost. It's a post that has seen 2.2k views in 4 years, it was not being consulted by anyone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 1 and a half views per day hardly strikes me as "not consulted by anyone."

Comment: @jpmc26: it would have more views, easily. 1.5 views per day is "hrm, nothing of use here, next search result", not "see this post over on SO for a good list" kind of traffic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  I don't fundamentally disagree; MIPS hasn't really been used as a viable architecture in a long time.  Something may have been lost, but it wasn't anything *significant*.  :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have a 5-year old question linked directly from one of Craig Ringer's blog posts that only has 437 views, so I'm not convinced of your math.

Comment: @Makoto I fully understand and appreciate your answer below.  Thank you for your clarification, and I intend to answer more carefully in the future.  To your comment about MIPS not being relevant, that just isn't true.  There is a large market for MIPS devices out there.  As I mentioned in my post, there are companies that deploy many miliions of devices based on MIPS architecture.

Comment: I’ve got to hand it to you! Even after your IMO(?) obviously promotional answers were closed, you’ve managed to hiddenly promote your product on Meta and get positive reactions and answers relying purely on the recent overpoliteness and sense of guilt of SO community. Even I have to be polite and admit that there is no way around that - we kinda obligated to explain what spam is and provide actual  examples of it. Except maybe if your current meta-question turned out to be a duplicate of someone elses :).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm quite happy you elected to step forward and discuss this, so let's have a constructive discussion about it.

First, to your main conjecture:

> My understanding based on these posts ... was that self-promotion is allowed, as long as its done sparingly, and it answers the question.

...but *did* you answer the questions, though?

Let's look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135942/is-jvm-for-mips-available/54408407 (10K+ only).  The question states:

> I am looking for java support on mips. Is the JVM for Mips available? I tried downloading the jdk for java support but it is not available for mips. How can I port java on mips?

The empirical answer is one of either:

- Yes, it's supported *now*, or
- No, it's not supported.

"Java support" has been a buzz word with Oracle's recent change to their license *and* release models, since "support" now only happens with long-term releases, which is a paid service.  In 2015 this probably didn't matter that much since Oracle hadn't done anything this radical, but it's fairly clear from the tone of the OP that they are looking for an official port.

What your answer supplied was more of a promotional aspect of your product and service than actually answering the question.  Here's the rub, emphasis mine:

> In general, in order for us to provide a release for any platform (MIPS architecture, or otherwise), **we would simply need to be provided with a toolchain**. Once the toolchain is provided, it usually takes us very little time to **provide an evaluation VM binary**.

...So the answer is, I have to contact your company and pay money.  Sure, we've had people sell that before on this site, but that's not really an answer.  That's more facilitating a *discussion* about your services than actually answering anything, which is hammered home by your ending statement:

> If you have any questions, I'd be happy to answer them!

***Oops.***

We don't do discussions on Stack Overflow.  We do questions and answers.

The example [shown to you in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/5958455) was an example of an acceptable self-promotion, since:

- It provided an answer directly in the answer
- It didn't require anyone to initiate a discussion with anyone else about the product
- It didn't elicit discussion about the tool or library
- If the site went dark the answer could still be *somewhat* useful

Just in the future, be *careful* about the self-promotion you want to do.  While your service may actually be valuable, if your service went dark and we had someone who needed this knowledge look at your answer, they'd be frustrated that they couldn't get a solution to a problem after searching high and low.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the other answers deal with the basics of self-promotion and what kind of post is appropriate in the site, and how your posts were a (very) bad fit for Stack Overflow; but it seems that you may have learnt something from your previous mistakes and are now more aware about those rules, or so you claim.

But regarding your specific question:

> All that being said, are there any steps that I can/should take to unlock the above posts so that they could be edited/improved?

Nothing. I do not think that those are salvageable. There is no way to make them good. And they are posted to off-topic questions anyway (something it appears you still have trouble identifying: answer good, on-topic questions; answering the other kind is not helpful for the site). So changing them completely so they are different but good answers is not something to be desired either.

The difficulty of your situation is that answer-ban is something that I believe not even a moderator could lift, since it's wholy automatic. Once you are in that hole, the only way to dig yourself out is by following these [steps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Asking a moderator to clear the spam flag from either of these posts to help you get unbanned seems unfair, and counterproductive. The posts were spammy. They were correctly flagged and deleted.

Your only possible recourse regarding these answers, and the situation they put you in* would be to try to ask for a [post dissasociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285385/how-do-i-disassociate-a-question-from-my-account), explaining **why** you are asking for it. Maybe that could help you getting unbanned, although I'm not sure it woul work. Whoever responds to your message might tell you more, if you ask clearly and explain the situation.

<sub>* if indeed it is only these two answers the ones responsible from your ban: there could be other badly received posts affecting your account that you had deleted and don't remember right now</sub>

Comment: Answer bans, like question bans, are automatic and not liftable by any other metric than having better answers.  I do see this answer as accurate and valuable since this adds the point I missed - these answers are essentially written off.  OP gets burned; OP learns for the future.  I don't *think* it'd take two answers to nudge to an answer ban but it's not a positive trend, so I don't believe they should worry about that just yet.

Comment: @Makoto The OP [mentioned in a different question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379672/how-can-i-improve-this-answer) that they are already answer banned,which is why I mention the answer ban angle. The reason they want to try to improve these questions is to get out of a ban, and they claim they have no other posts. No idea how the algo works, and neither if the OP is correct in saying they have no other badly received deleted posts; I just took their clamis at face value. To have a heavy handed ban for someone with a couple spam-deleted posts in a row didn't seem impossible.

Comment: Oh, that's right - they *were* marked as spam.  That's -200 reputation right there.  That's not a hole you can climb out of.

Answer (score 4):

You answer your question in your question.

> Self-promotion is allowed, as long as its done sparingly

This means that most of your answers must be about other things, and not include any promotion at all. You only have 1 answer like that out of 3.

This is why they are marked as spam. When you posted them, your sole presence seemed to be for the purpose of posting spam.

Currently your deleted answers would not be a fit for Stack Overflow even if they didn't promote anything as you don't really answer the question. You are too chatty, don't provide an answer, and solicit extra contact, which are all big no-nos and red flags.

Stack Overflow looks for answers that are short, concise, which you can look at and get the answer *without having to ask for any extra details or tools*.

My advice is to try and answer a few questions on a subject you are familiar with, where you don't promote your product. Build up some reputation, and get to know how Stack Overflow works, and what is looked for. The one non-promotion answer you currently have is good, keep it up. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 3):

First, I'm glad you're aware of our self-promotion policies and have gone through them, as well as general advices on self-promo.

I'm not sure how to start this off, so let me present you with [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/5958455) of a good self-promotion first.

But what's the difference between the example and your promotion?

Just my humble opinion, it's that the other user has many other positive contributions to the site (Stack Overflow), and the promotional answer is also a valid answer to the question. Your answers follow the latter point since they're also valid answers to the questions. That's good, BUT. The questions, as noted by Martijn, are off-topic themselves, as they're asking people to find other resources. As said in the "close reason" text, "such questions tend to attract spam", and it's a reason why we take answers to such questions more seriously. I'd also like to point out that despite being valid, your answers doesn't add much value to the site and can IMO hardly be counted as "positive contribution".

The other point, "other contributions", could also be a reason why your answers are considered spam. The author of the example answer presented above has many other decent answers, and we trust them more that they don't *come for* promotion. You have only 1 visible answer at the point, where two other of your answers are promotional. We allow some self-promotion if they come to answer, but we generally take it as spam when it comes *with the intention* to promote, which people may have thought so by looking at the way your answers are written.

The latter one is what I want to emphasize: Come to answer, not come to promote.

Bottom line: Thank you for your understanding of Stack Overflow and our policies. Keep the right thing in mind and you'll be another good contributor.